# Sanity and Next.JS - My frontend don't read my sanityProject

Tags: typescript, next.js, sanity

https://github.com/EzequielMadrid/pro-portfolio

I try to read the sanity, and I'd like to show all the data that I'm calling, and in my frontend, the socials aren't seen. Socials're my first call.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ey @KargWare ! there's my repo! thanks for your time